# Length of the FIR filter in LMS algorithm

Tags: adaptive-filters, adaptive-algorithms, lms

I'm working on an interference cancellation problem where interfering signals are two linear FM chirps of different slopes and the data signal is a spread spectrum signal. I wanted to know how does the length of the filter affect the convergence ?

Comment: The longer the filter the slower it will converge.

Comment: Hi Matt thank you for answering. You mean the overall convergence would increase but it wouldn't affect the convergence of individual modes right ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: does having a longer filter mean that we have less bandwidth (i.e. finer resolution) in our filter ? I'm somehow mixing up the effect that the step-size and filter length has on the filter performance.